# Como converter uma variável string para int?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo

Como declaro de forma correta um valor *inteiro*, pois ele esta retornando que minhas variáveis são *strings*.

```
n1 = input("informe um número ")
n2 = input("informe um número ")

soma = n1 + n2
print ("O resultado da soma de ", soma)
```

> informe um número 25
>   informe um número 25
>   2525
>
> >>>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Como já foi mencionado nas outras respostas, o retorno da [função `input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) é do tipo *string*, o mesmo é válido para a [função `raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) no Python *2.x*.

```
numero1 = int(input("Informe um numero: "))
numero2 = int(input("Informe um numero: "))
```

Considere também tratar possíveis *exceções* que possam ocorrer, por exemplo a [exceção `ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) que é lançada quando uma função recebe um argumento que tem o tipo certo, mas um valor inválido.

Veja:

```
try:
    numero1 = int(input("Informe um numero: "))
    numero2 = int(input("Informe um numero: "))

    soma = numero1 + numero2
    print ("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(numero1, numero2, soma))

except ValueError:
    print("Somente numeros sao aceitos. Tente novamente.")
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](https://repl.it/BJNM)

Comment: ut84, tratando do Value Error, exemplo quando defino valor int para variavel x só que é inserido um valor real nesta variavel ? E muito obrigado por sua explicação.

Comment: @leogif Nesse caso, ao invés de `int`, deveria ser usado [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). Veja [**esse exemplo**](https://repl.it/BIy4).

Answer (score 7):

Você tem que converter a *string*, que é o retorno da função `input`, para um número:

```
n1 = input ("informe um número ")
n2 = input ("informe um número ")
soma = int(n1) + int(n2)
print ("O resultado da soma de", soma)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Tp5LsP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fwqjcxhk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertToInt.py).

[Documentação da função](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: bigown, vlw Muito Obrigado. Como funciona a função def ?

Comment: bigown, você pode me indicar um livro sobre python 3 para iniciantes ? E muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não gosto de indicar algo a não ser que eu confie muito e em Python não conheço nada que confie 100% (não quer dizer que não tenha, só não conheço a fundo). O lugar certo para achar esta informação é a nossa *tag* sobre o tema. Não sei se as indicações lá são boas mas tem uma chance: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Comment: n1 = input("informe sua nota do 1º Bimestre ")
    n2 = input("informe sua nota do 2º Bimestre ")
    n3 = input("informe sua nota do 3º Bimestre ") 
    n4 = input("informe sua nota do 4º Bimestre ")
    media = float((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)) / int(4)
    print("A média é",media)

    informe sua nota do 1º Bimestre 2
    informe sua nota do 2º Bimestre 2
    informe sua nota do 3º Bimestre 2
    informe sua nota do 4º Bimestre 2
A média é 555.5

Answer (score 7):

O input reconhece os valores em forma de string. então você deveria fazer o seguinte:

```
soma = int(n1) + int(n2)
```

o int(), torna os valores números

Comment: Arnaldo Badin, vlw Muito Obrigado. Como funciona a função def ?

Comment: Arnaldo Badin, você pode me indicar um livro sobre python 3 para iniciantes ? E muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: a função é usada para realizar algo apenas chamando ela, exemplo: def printX(): x = 10 print(x)............... eu recomendo você ver esse cara aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVp1vrfL_w4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M    esse cara é sensacional, assistindo isso você fica pro em python ;)

Answer (score -1):

Você deve definir qual o tipo da sua variável, no Python não é diferente e os tipos são:

```
int = número inteiro
float = número decimal
str = texto
```

para o seu problema devemos colocar

```
n1 = int(input("informe um número "))
n2 = int(input("informe um número "))

soma = n1 + n2
print ("O resultado da soma de ", soma)
```

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia definir o valor int para o input desde o início:

```
n1 = int(input("informe um número "))
n2 = int(input("informe um número "))

soma = n1 + n2
print ("O resultado da soma de ", soma)
```

ou poderia definir o valor int depois, na variável:

```
n1 = input("informe um número ")
n2 = input("informe um número ")

soma = int(n1) + int(n2)
print ("O resultado da soma de ", soma)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n1 = input("informe um número ")
n2 = input("informe um número ")
n1 = int(n1)
n2 = int(n2)
soma = n1 + n2
print ("O resultado da soma de ", soma)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

um modo simples para isto abaixo.

```
while True:
    try:
        variavel = int(input('Digite um número: '))
        break

    except ValueError:
        False
```

Comment: Gedson, por que há um `False` no `except`? Não seria melhor utilizar o `pass` visto que você deseja ignorar a exceção?

Comment: Olá Anderson! Então, eu estou aprendendo Python agora. Fiz este exemplo aí para o usuário não sair do WHILE enquanto não digitar um número correto. Com o PASS o WHILE é interrompido.

Comment: Não, pass não faz o while ser interrompido, o break que iria fazer isso.

Comment: o código é o seguinte. 
a pessoa digita qualquer coisa e o BRAKE só ocorre se o que foi digitado for um INTEIRO,
se tiver algum erro aí vem FALSE e o WHILE continua.

Comment: É justamente isso que eu estou dizendo. O `False` dentro de `except` não tem função alguma no código. Se não tem função, deveria ser o `pass`. O `pass` não serve para encerrar o laço, mas sim para informar que nada será feito naquele bloco de código. Dei mais detalhes sobre isso em [Qual a real utilidade do pass neste caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240994/5878)

Comment: Agora sim! Entendi 
Fiz o teste aqui com PASS no lugar de FALSE e funciona tb!
hehehehe
eu estava bem confuso. Pois eu mudava o BREAK pra PASS e num funcionava