# Qual a real utilidade do pass neste caso?

Tags: python, django, palavras-reservadas

Estou trabalhando na adaptação de um projeto django já criado. Durante a análise do código me deparei com o seguinte trecho:

```
def objects_delete_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        try:
            obj.delete()
        except (NOT_ALLOWED_ON_NONLEAF, ValueError):
            messages.error(request, AdminErrorMessages.MUST_BE_EMPTY)
    pass
```

Tomando como referência os conceitos passados [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-break-pass-e-continue-em-python) fiquei com uma duvida da necessidade do pass neste método. Se há a necessidade do uso não modifica o significado dela para a linguagem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não existe utilidade para este caso. A única função do `pass` é funcionar como um *placeholder* em estruturas que demandam uma expressão obrigatoriamente, mas que nenhuma lógica deva ser executada. Quando um `pass` é executado, nada acontece, literalmente, mas ainda assim é considerado como uma expressão válida.

É normalmente utilizada quando você quer ter a definição de uma estrutura, mas não quer implementar a respectiva lógica. Por exemplo, definir uma função:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

A função é definida, pode ser chamada, mas nada acontece. Sem o `pass`, um erro de sintaxe seria disparado. Seria o equivalente a deixar as chave vazia em algumas outras linguagens:

```
function foo() {

}
```

Neste caso, como o `pass` está no mesmo nível de indentação que o `for`, ele pertence diretamente ao escopo da função `objects_delete_action`. Porém, como o próprio `for` já fornece a expressão que a declaração da função demanda, o `pass` é desnecessário - e provavelmente continua no código porque alguém esqueceu de excluí-lo.

É importante ressaltar que mesmo que `queryset` seja um conjunto vazio e que nenhuma iteração do laço seja executada, o `for` continua sendo uma expressão válida e é analisada pelo interpretador. Mesmo nesse caso o `pass` é desnecessário. Prova disso, basta tentar criar um laço que itera uma lista vazia:

```
def foo():
    for value in []:
        print(value)
```

Mesmo que nenhuma iteração ocorra, já que é uma lista vazia, a expressão continua válida e nenhum erro de sintaxe é disparado.

Comment: Compreendi. Muito Obrigado.