# Erro Sistema para fila de Clientes Python

Tags: python

Estou programando um sistema de fila porem tem um erro que nao consigo resolver
´´´python

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

if comando == supervisor :

```
positivo = 'sim'
negativo = 'nao'
lançar1 == 'lançar_pc1'
lançar2 == 'lançar_pc2'
lançar3 == 'lançar_pc3'
lançar4 == 'lançar_pc4'
lançar5 == 'lançar_pc5'
lançar6 == 'lançar_pc6'
lançar7 == 'lançar_pc7'
lançar8 == 'lançar_pc8'
lançar9 == 'lançar_pc9'
lançar10 == 'lançar_pc10'
lançar11 == 'lançar_pc11'
mostrar == 'verfilas'

print('Bem vinda Monalisa')
print('Caso queira fazer o lançamento de um cliente digite lançar_numerodocomputador')
print('Exemplo lançar_pc2')
comandomona = input('Digite aqui o comando: ')


if comandomona == mostrar :

elif comandomona == lançar1 :

    arquivo1 = open('pc1.txt','a') # abrindo modo escrita
    print('Separando Por duas barras //')
    print('Digite o número do cliente , CNPJ , Nome , e dia que o cliente entrou em contato.')
    dadopc1 = input('Por favor digite conforme as instruções acima: ')
    arquivo.write('{}\n'.format(dadopc1))
    print('Lançado com sucesso\n')
    arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
            #posteriormente no modo de leitura
elif comandomona == lançar2 :

    arquivo2 = open('pc2.txt','a') # abrindo modo escrita
    print('Separando Por duas barras //')
    print('Digite o número do cliente , CNPJ , Nome , e dia que o cliente entrou em contato.')
    dadopc1 = input('Por favor digite conforme as instruções acima: ')
    arquivo.write('{}\n'.format(dadopc2))
    print('Lançado com sucesso\n')
    arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
            #posteriormente no modo de leitura    
elif comandomona == lançar3 :

    arquivo3 = open('pc3.txt','a') # abrindo modo escrita
    print('Separando Por duas barras //')
    print('Digite o número do cliente , CNPJ , Nome , e dia que o cliente entrou em contato.')
    dadopc3 = input('Por favor digite conforme as instruções acima: ')
    arquivo.write('{}\n'.format(dadopc3))
    print('Lançado com sucesso\n')
    arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
            #posteriormente no modo de leitura
elif comandomona == lançar4 :

    arquivo4 = open('pc1.txt','a') # abrindo modo escrita
    print('Separando Por duas barras //')
    print('Digite o número do cliente , CNPJ , Nome , e dia que o cliente entrou em contato.')
    dadopc4 = input('Por favor digite conforme as instruções acima: ')
    arquivo.write('{}\n'.format(dadopc4))
    print('Lançado com sucesso\n')
    arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
            #posteriormente no modo de leitura                                              
else:
```

´´´
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

erro acima 
está dando nessa linha 
elif comandomona == lançar1 :

Comment: o if a cima esta vazio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if comandomona == mostrar :

elif comandomona == lançar1 :
    ...
```

Quando você faz um `if` o interpretador espera que haja um bloco de código dentro dele. Isto é, após a linha com o `if`, o interpretador esperará que haja um bloco de código com um nível a mais de indentação. Como você não colocou, ele entenderá que o seu `elif` é o bloco que deveria estar dentro do `if`. Como ele não possui o nível de indentação a mais, gera o erro de indentação.

Não faz sentido ter no código um bloco de `if` vazio, então você pode removê-lo:

```py
if comandomona == lançar1 :
    ...
```

Mas se quer mantê-lo por alguma razão, seja para lembrar de implementar mais tarde, você precisa informar ao interpretador que não deseja executar nada ali. Para isso você pode utilizar a expressão `pass`:

```py
if comandomona == mostrar :
    pass
elif comandomona == lançar1 :
    ...
```

Pois a `pass` nada mais é que uma expressão neutra, sem efeitos, que já satisfaz o bloco lógico dentro do `if`.

- [Qual a real utilidade do pass neste caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240994/5878)