# Exercício Gasto de Combustível em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou iniciando em Python e estou fazendo alguns exercícios, fiz esse de gasto de combustível, mas ele não me mostra o fim do programa, ou seja, o resultado, qual é o erro?

```
nome = input("Qual é o seu nome?")

gasto = input("{}, digite o tempo gasto na viagem (em horas): ".format(nome))

velocidade = input('{}, digite agora a velocidade média praticado na viagem: '.format(nome))

consumo = float(velocidade/12)

print("Foram gastos ", consumo, " litros de combustível.")
```

O erro gerado é:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/ralf/PycharmProjects/ProjetoPython/Gasto_Combustivel.py", line 4, in 
>       consumo = float(velocidade / 12)
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Seja bem vindo Ralf, a resposta do Fchagas está correta. Entretanto, aconselho você a ler está pergunta: [Como converter uma variável string para int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87584/como-converter-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-string-para-int) Te ajudará a compreender melhor a conversão e possíveis tratamentos  com exceções.

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples. A função `input` retorna **sempre** uma string, independentemente se o usuário digitou somente números. Na linguagem Python não é possível realizar operações aritméticas com `strings` ( mesmo sendo números em formato de `string` ). Para corrigir este erro, você deverá convertê-lo para `float` ou `int`. Exemplo:

Este código dará o mesmo erro:

```
print("98.3"/12)
```

Este código **não** dará erro:

```
print(float("98.3")/12)
```

Agora que já sabemos sobre isso, como ficaria o seu código corrigido ? Ficaria desta forma:

```
nome = input("Qual é o seu nome?")

gasto = float(input("{}, digite o tempo gasto na viagem (em horas): ".format(nome)))

velocidade = float(input('{}, digite agora a velocidade média praticado na viagem: '.format(nome)))

consumo = velocidade/12

print("Foram gastos ", consumo, " litros de combustível.")
```

É importante também dizer que, operações de divisão (/) em Python **sempre** retornarão um `float`. Por isso não é necessário a conversão no cálculo da divisão. Exemplo:

```
>>> 10/2
5.0
```

Comment: Certamente, este foi o meu erro, obrigado pelo esclarecimento, Jean.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você deve converter a *velocidade* para `int` ou `float`:

```py
velocidade = int(input('{}, digite agora a velocidade média praticado na viagem: '.format(nome)))
```

Ou

```py
velocidade = float(input('{}, digite agora a velocidade média praticado na viagem: '.format(nome)))
```

Ou ainda:

```py
consumo = float(int(velocidade)/12)
```

Comment: Mas por que você precisa converter o resultado da divisão, que já é um float, para outro float?