# Como carregar valores inteiros de um arquivo txt? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero carregar um dicionário onde o arquivo texto `.txt` contém informações do tipo `String`, porém, quero que os valores sejam carregados do tipo `Inteiro`.

```
{'11322567498': '[0],[0]'}
```

Note que os valores estão sempre sendo carregados como `String`.

Código que estou usando para carregar os valores em um dicionário:

```
def carregar_reservas(reserva):
    with open('reservas.txt') as doc:
        for line in doc:
            (cpf, name) = line.split()
            reserva[cpf] = name
```

Comment: Primeiramente, gostaria de alertá-lo que apesar de o CPF ser um número, o ideal é considerá-lo como ```String```, visto que existem números de CPF que iniciam com o caracter ```0```. Sendo assim ao fazer um *Typecast* do tipo ```String``` para ```Inteiro```, o mesmo seria removido.

Comment: Para resolver a sua questão, você pode simplesmente realizar a conversão do valor do tipo ```String``` para o tipo ```Inteiro```. Saiba mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87584/como-converter-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-string-para-int

Comment: No caso, eu tentei fazer isso, só que no valor da direita ou seja, '[0],[0]' só que acaba dando erro.  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0],[0]'

Answer (score 2):

@UserDel,

A variável `name` possui caracteres que não podem ser convertidos em número. No caso `[`,  `]` e `,`

O ideal é limpar sua variável antes de converter.

Usando o comando abaixo, você irá retirar uma série de caracteres indesejados.

```
name = name.translate({ord(c): "" for c in " !@#$%^&*()[]{};:./<>?\\|`~-=_+"})
```

Perceba que a vírgula não fez parte do comando acima. Entendo que a mesma seja divisor de decimal. Sendo assim, por fim, você precisaria substituí-la por ponto com o `replace`

```
name = name.replace(",", ".")
```

Por fim, transforme em inteiro com `int(name)` ou float com `float(name)`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> name = "!#[10]$, [02]"
>>> name = name.translate({ord(c): "" for c in " !@#$%^&*()[]{};:./<>?\\|`~-=_+"})
>>> name
'10,02'
>>> name = name.replace(",", ".")
>>> name
'10.02'
>>> float(name)
10.02
>>>
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Aparentemente funciona, mas e se ao invés de retirar todos os caracteres indesejados, utilizar-se expressão regular *Regex*. Acredito que seria uma opção mais viável, devido ao fato de não ter que realizar o tratamento de caracter por caracter além de não deixar passar nenhum outro caracter especial não esperado como ```º, ª```, além de ficar mais simples.

Comment: Concordo que o regex ajuda em vários problemas. Mas, algumas vezes, ele acarreta em mais tempo para criar a expressão do que se resolvesse de uma outra forma.