# Não consigo executar os comandos if e elif

Tags: python, pycharm

Estou fazendo um curso de TI e estou tendo minhas primeiras aulas com Python, estou usando o Pycharm porém o código que estou fazendo não executa a função `"if"` independente do que eu bote como resposta.

```
print("menu")
reg= input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: ")
if reg == 1:
    P1 = input("Digite o produto 1: ")
    vp1 = float(input("Digite o valor do produto 1 : "))
    P2 = input("Digite o produto 2: ")
    vp2 = float(input("Digite o valor do produto 2:  "))
    calculo = vp1 + vp2
    print(calculo)
else:
    print("Sinto muito, não podemos te ajudar em mais nada")
```

Comment: Se você usar o comando `type(reg)` para descobrir o porquê. Está relacionado com tipos, você está lendo uma `string` e está comparando com um `integer`.

Comment: meu deus kkk eu sou muito noob ainda, onde eu insiro esse type(reg) no código? string eu sei o que é, integer é o mesmo que int?

Comment: Por favor verifique se o conteúdo que eu postei como resposta pode ser útil para a comunidade. Caso possua alguma sugestão de melhoria basta informar no campo de comentários.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está lendo um valor `str` e está comparando com um valor `int`.

Como comentei na resposta anterior é possível verificar o problema utilizando a função `type(reg)`, pode ser adicionado ao seu código logo depois da declaração da variável `reg`.

```
reg= input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: ")
type(reg)
# <class 'str'>
```

Desta forma quando você faz a comparação no comando condicional if, utilizando o seu código:

```
if reg == 1:
```

Supondo que tenha apertado a tecla <kbd>1</kbd> (apenas uma vez) e tenha apertado <kbd>enter</kbd>, então é como se estivesse comparando se a str `'1'` é igual ao valor numérico 1.

Existem algumas abordagens para resolver o problema

### Converter o valor lido para integer

```
reg= int(input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: "))
type(reg)
```

Verifique que utilizando esta abordagem é possível ocorrer uma exception ao fazer a conversão para integer, por exemplo se o usuário apertar a tecla <kbd>a</kbd> vai ocorrer um erro. Então é necessário tratar este caso.

Segue um exemplo de como tratar este problema:

```
try:
    reg= int(input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: "))
except:
    print('Houve um erro ao ler sua resposta não foi possível transformar em um valor númerico inteiro')
```

### Comparar o valor lido como str

Neste caso o condicional do seu if deve ser comparado com a str `'1'`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
reg= input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: ")
if len(reg) > 0 and reg[0] == '1':
```

Desta forma simplifica um pouco a maneira de ler as opções pois não é necessário tratar a exceção de converter para valores inteiros assim basta fazer um ajuste para ler apenas o primeiro caractere do valor lido.

Para saber mais sobre o comando [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) e [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html), consulte a documentação oficial.

Answer (score 0):

A função input() aceita uma string como entrada, um literal.
Quando na variavel reg a atribuição a função, ele ira compara uma string.

no if , esta comparando  um literal com um numero inteiro.
Poderia  usar dessa maneira caso seja duas string.

```
if reg == 'x':
  ...faça algo
```

Na situação atual do código, esta comparando uma entrada do tipo string com o numero 1, para que compare a opção, faça igual a entrada do tipo float que fez logo abaixo, mas usando um tipo inteiro dessa forma.

```
reg= int(input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: "))
```

informando que é um tipo inteiro.

Então estara correto essa verificação:

```
if reg == 1: 
  ...faça algo
```

comparando dois inteiros.

```
print("menu") 
reg= int(input("Deseja registrar seus itens?\n(1)Sim\n(2)Não\nDigite sua resposta: "))# do tipo inteiro
if reg == 1: 
    P1 = input("Digite o produto 1: ")
    vp1 = float(input("Digite o valor do produto 1 : ")) # input do tipo float
    P2 = input("Digite o produto 2: ") # entrada literal
    vp2 = float(input("Digite o valor do produto 2:  "))# entrada do tipo float
    calculo = vp1 + vp2
    print(calculo)
else:
    print("Sinto muito, não podemos te ajudar em mais nada")
```

Comment: É necessário tratar exceção ao ler um inteiro.

Comment: se digitar um literal no lugar do inteiro mas para fins didatico simples compreender como lidar com o tipo de dados é significativo para iniciar os estudos.https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87584/como-converter-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-string-para-int